# Insomnia Question - Discussion

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/is-insomnia-a-valid-reason-to-file-for-a-sick-leave) seems like it has great potential to yo-yo from close/reopen.

I am creating this to discuss the question rather than simply vote/comment up a storm.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in order for us to stop it from yo-yo-ing we first need to discuss *why* it might yo yo in the first place.

This question seems to balance on the fringe of an interesting work place issue and something that is going to differ greatly depending on location and culture.

I think this would be an interesting question to keep around because in most workplaces, being 'tired' isn't synonymous with being ill despite the degrading effect it has on both your ability to work and your general health.

I think that if we assume all workplaces will say 'no' to it and then have answers provide solid, evidence backed points that one could use as the basis of encouraging a company to understand the influence of insomnia then the question could be very solid.

For example, answers might point out its effects on ones health and efficiency in the workplace.

Answer (score 1):

In places I've worked, it's common for people to not come in if they haven't had enough sleep. Also, there's the question of places where the work is dangerous, like airline pilots. Then there's the military, where sleeplessness is just part of the job.

Thus, I agree this is an interesting question that will also yield different answers. Perhaps editing the question to focus on a specific industry might help and editing to make one of the requirements of answering that people provide fact-based explanations or share experiences that happened to them that back up the answer.

**UPDATE:** I closed this post for now; the top voted answer is a one line answer with no back up references. The question was also edited to ask a non-workplace question.

I made this decision by looking at the [Six Subjective Guidelines to a Good Subjective Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and asked myself if this question met those guidelines. For most of those guidelines, the question in it's current form doesn't meet what's listed in the blog.

I think this question could work if it were somehow more focused on something non-theoretical, or even if answerers followed the six guidelines in answers. I've seen good answers save a so-so question.

Comment: As you rightly say though this can pop up in many industries, if we focus on answering only one of them will we accept repeat questions that want answers for a different industry? If not, then couldn't your point about the dangers be factored as a point to think about in an answer following my suggested format?

Comment: @RhysW - I don't see harm in multiple questions for multiple industries, so long as the questions don't all sound like they were asked just for the sake of asking. When people show up to our site with a real problem, the questions take on a uniqueness that can't be replicated by simply copy/pasting the questions and changing the industry name. What's more, focusing on the op's specific industry leaves the door open for more great, valuable content for our site that's similar but not quite an exact duplicate. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yup, answers it perfectly, just wanted to be clear on where our boundaries lie on similar, potentially related, questions

Comment: I think there is a better way to get a canonical answer.  That would be to ask how to determine if insomnia would be an acceptable reason for calling in sick.  But i still dislike this because it is mostly asking for opinion.  The question is asking for judgement on when its right.  There is nothing constructive about that question that makes me think it should be salvaged.

Comment: Would any answer you give to this question actually vary from industry to industry by a large [enough] margin?  A standard disclaimer always applies: situations/firms vary, check with the authority that matters for authoritative answers, but this is what I know or would expect or would suggest, yes?  I think it would be better to start from a general answer, and then, as needed, enumerate notable categorical exceptions or deviations.

Comment: I think the issue is that the question is asking solely about whether insomnia is an acceptable reason to take off, which is a very narrow yes/no question. If it were more broad, "What criteria should be considered before taking sick leave?" would be a far more useful answer (and would likely cover insomnia too).